# Conflicting counts of unanswered questions

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

I have noticed that the two routes to getting unanswered questions show different counts.

For example on Academia.SE, if I click "Unanswered" on the top banner, it says there are 109 unanswered questions.  If, on the other hand, I click "Questions" and go to the "Unanswered" sub-set, it says there are 118 unanswered questions.

This seems wrong, that there should be two conflicting numbers for what the site leads me to believe should be identical queries.

---

Further investigation reveals the exact difference, which leads me to believe that we are definitely dealing with a bug.  Because apparently I have nothing better to do with my time, I ran a diff by hand on the two sets of Academia unanswered questions.

The 9 questions in the "Questions --> Unanswered" that are not in "Unanswered --> Votes" break down as follows:

- Two are negatively voted questions with no answers, e.g. [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/43654/22733)
- Seven are positively voted questions with negatively voted answers, e.g., [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29211/22733)

The first might be a desired behavior, but if so it should be documented.  The second is clearly a problem because the most highly voted unanswered question on the site is not listed, just because somebody gave it a crappy answer!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I have investigated further and determined the criteria that are causing questions to be on one list but not the other.  The prior questions have not identified these criteria, and at least one of them is clearly causing undesirable behavior.

Comment: How is this duplicate? The other answers conflict with the observed behavior of "Unanswered" not including upvoted questions with down voted answers.